# parseFloat() is not parsing all strings in my array. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I am making arrays out of columns in a table that I use to graph Flot charts. I start by working my way down the column and storing each column as its own array, then I check the column to the right and repeat.

Everything has been working great, except for this one tiny issue I am having where I am reading out the string values from the last column and parsing them into floats. All the values in last column parse to floats except for a few. Sometimes it's the 0th and 2nd element in the array, or sometimes the 0th and 1st.

Here's what it looks like when I `console.log` the arrays:

[image: Here's what it looks like when I <code>console.log</code> the arrays:]

The table also known as `#maintable`:

[image]

As you can see in the last array the 0th and 2nd values in the array are returned as strings, but the rest are returned as floats.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="chart_container" class="widget-body col-md-12" style="height: 453px;">
    <section id="mainchart" class="col-md-12" style="height: 453px;"></section>
</div>
```

---

JS:

```
var slices = [];
var sliceNames, sliceNights, sliceNightsAvg, sliceRevs = [];
var sliceSet = [];
var colorPalette = [];



//Get number of columns by counting number of cells in the header row
var numOfColumns = $("#maintable tr th").length;

function getCellData(array, columnNum) {
    $("#maintable tr td:nth-child(" + columnNum + ")").each(function (k, v) {
        if(!array) {
            array = [];
        }

        //Store the slice labels in array
        array[k] = $(this).text();

        //Remove any long whitespace from cell
        array[k] = array[k].trim();



        //Check if the data in the cell is a number or not
        if (parseFloat(array[k]) % 1 === 0) {
            //Filter the values

            array[k] = array[k].replace("$", "");
            array[k] = array[k].replace(",", "");
            array[k] = array[k].replace("K", "000");
            array[k] = array[k].replace("M", "000000");

            //If there's a decimal
            /*if (array[k].indexOf(".") !== -1) {
                //Then parse as a float
                array[k] = parseFloat(array[k]);
            } else {
                //Otherwise, parse as an integer
                array[k] = parseInt(array[k]);
            }*/

            array[k] = parseFloat(array[k]);
        }
    });

    return array;
}

//Get cell data
sliceNames = getCellData(sliceNames, 1);
sliceNights = getCellData(sliceNights, 2);
sliceNightsAvg = getCellData(sliceNightsAvg, 3);
sliceRevs = getCellData(sliceRevs, 4);

console.log(sliceNames);
console.log(sliceNights);
console.log(sliceNightsAvg);
console.log(sliceRevs);

//Loop through and create the slices
for (var i = 0; i < sliceNames.length; i++) {
    if (!sliceSet) {
        sliceSet = [];
    }

    //Setup the slices
    var slice = {};
    slice.label = sliceNames[i];
    slice.data = sliceNights[i];

    //Push the slice to the set of slices
    sliceSet.push(slice);
}

//Plot the Pie chart
plotPieChart(sliceSet);


function plotPieChart(data) {
    $.plot($("#mainchart"), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                innerRadius: 0.3,
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    threshold: 0.01
                }
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            },
            legend: {
                show: true
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `parseFloat(array[k]) % 1 === 0` checks if the number is an *integer*. It will be false for numbers that have a fractional part. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I would use `isNaN()` to check if it is a number.

Comment: @Juhana This is true. But I am still a little confused how it's worked for the other ones?

Comment: Consider using [`Number(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead of `parseInt`/`parseFloat`; it has fewer edge cases.

Comment: Juhana is right about parseFloat(array[k]) % 1 === 0 returning false for non-integers, I was going to include that in a formal answer, but how are any floats coming in as the correct type at all? Unless the source value sometime comes in as a number already, there is another issue in addition to that one.

Comment: @wedstrom The numbers are printed to the table first, and then read from the table using `array[k] = $(this).text()` which gives me string value. As shown in the picture though, most of the fractional numbers are being parsed from string to float.

Answer (score 1):

Some time there is an invisible character in a string, please remove this character. Please check length of the string, if length is greater than visible characters then invisible character is existed. this character is not ASCII character so I am unable to write here. The character code is "u+200E".

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to duplicate your results exactly(some numbers coming correctly but others not), but I am very confidant that switching `parseFloat(array[k]) % 1 === 0` to `!isNaN(array[k])` or similar will fix your issue.